# Frontend passing oauth token to dropwizard backend

Tags: oauth, restful-authentication, dropwizard

I'm looking for some advice on 'proxying' authentication for my application. i.e. using the same authentication on the front- and back- end of my application. The architecture consists of a DropWizard backend API and a NodeJS frontend.

Currently, the frontend is protected by Google OAuth and is working well. However, the backend is only protected by Basic authentication. The NodeJS server has the basic auth credentials embedded in it, to allow backend calls, which is not a great solution.

I'd like to know if there's a way to pass the OAuth credentials/token from the front end to the back end, so that I can lock down the back end more securely. Additionally, it would be nice to either keep the basic auth on the backend, or have a way to make OAuth backend api calls from the command line, using curl.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for but just in case you've missed it: https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/auth.html there is oauth support so to speak but all you get is a string. So you need to validate the token yourself somehow.

Comment: Yeah, I did see that. But that's for authenticating the backend. I can't make command line calls to the backend if it's protected using oauth. I need to combine basic and oauth authentication on the backend, and have the frontend pass credentials through.

Comment: What dropwizard provides as auth providers are not very complicated actually. You can create your own Auth factory and register that instead. Just combine these two https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-auth/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/auth/oauth/OAuthFactory.java https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-auth/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/auth/basic/BasicAuthFactory.java

Comment: Can someone show me a example of this string?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use something like a [VPC](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) to keep your back end server on a secure network. Give your front end a public-facing IP, but keep the back end internal, and only accept requests on the back end from that front end server, or just from the internal network. Then you don't need any authentication on the back end, and you can access it with VPN or another machine on the secure network.

Comment: But that's essentially the same as my current setup, where the backend is protected by one basic auth user. It also limits the ability of other users to build their own clients to call into my backend.